# Traffic shaping during a MITM attack

Tags: networking

In my local network there are about 10 computers. I setup ettercap to do arp poisoning between a particular host and the gateway and now I can see that host's traffic.

What I wanted to do next is to implement traffic shaping. Since the host is running through my machine, hence using my ethernet card, I assumed that by installing /using tc or equivalent (personally used wondershaper) I should be able to limit the traffic of the host.

While these tools *do* limit **MY** bandwidth, it doesn't seem to affect the remote host passing through me.

WHat am I doing wrong and how do I reach the objective?

Comment: This isn't an InfoSec question, but a routing question. Voting to move to SuperUser.

Comment: This is rather a job for a good network engineer.

Answer (score 1):

`Wondershaper` is a traffic shaping made easy tool for a consumer alone behind his ISP. It isn't suited for your derivated traffic control.

What you want to perform here is a real traffic shaping inside your network.
You will have to shape your derivated traffic, and your own.

I suggest you to ask this question on:
[Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/)
with the care to avoid confusion between QoS and traffic shaping.